# Cross-sectional demeaning in R

Tags: r

I found quite some questions on cross sectional demeaning, but I'm failing to properly apply them to my case in R. I have a dataframe with a panel structure (id + year) and I have to demean all my explanatory variables in the data frame in the following way:

[image: Equation of a demeaned X]

where X_it is the explanatory variable at a given point in time and it is demeaned by the weighted average of a cross section at the same point in time where W_it is the weighting variable.

Here a reproducable example of what I've tried so far:

```
# A random data frame
df1  <- read.table(text="Country   Year   X1  X2    W
                         A         1990   10  20    40
                         A         1991   12  15    NA
                         A         1992   14  17    41
                         A         1993   17  NA    44
                         B         1990   20  NA    45
                         B         1991   NA  13    61
                         B         1992   12  12    67
                         B         1993   14  10    68", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

where `X1` and `X2` should be demeaned by the weighted average and the weight is `W`. For example, applying the formula from above the demeaned value of `X1` in 1990 would be: 10-(10*40+20*45)/40+45 = -5.29. Ideally, this demeaned value should be added to the dataframe in a seperate column i.e. as `dMX1`.

My approach was to use `weighted.mean` in my function such as:

```
demean <- colwise(function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) x - weighted.mean(x, df1$W) else x)

df2 <- ddply(df1, .(Year), demean)
```

However, I always get this error:

```
Error in weighted.mean.default(x, df1$W): 'x' and 'w' must have the same length
```

I don't know whether R is only grouping the explanatory variables by Year but not the weighting variable `W`? Or am I working with the wrong function to get this work?

I really appreciate any help!